# Shortcut for show in explorer texstudio

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

When I right click on a file in the structure section of texstudio, one of the options is "show in explorer". Is there a way to define a shortcut for this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts can be assigned only to Menu entries and to some basic editing functions as [shown in the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION05).

You can use a script in a [personal macro](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

This script will open the file explorer in the folder of the current file in the editor (uncomment the appropriate line for your operating system):

```
%SCRIPT
// needs TeXstudio v2.11.0 or newer
filename = app.getCurrentFileName()
workingDirectory = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("/"))
//system("explorer .", workingDirectory) //for windows - tested
//system("xdg-open .", workingDirectory) //for linux - tested
//system("open .", workingDirectory) //for mac - untested
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for windows. But can explain more about the system command. I have other issues by this command in windows

Comment: Dear alwaysask. please kindly see the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321534/latexdiff-script-for-texstudio for example.